# Eclipse IBM MobileFirst Platform v7.1 Application stack overflow error

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I made the configuration to Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 and Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) on Windows 7 Prof SP1 and Mac OS Sierra. I already have installed Java 1.7.0_79 for the project purposes (I can't update Java nor Eclipse). I need to deploy an IBM MobileFirst Platform v7.1 app.

I'm trying to clean an Eclipse project with MobileFirst Platform plugin added, but when I run the command (menubar > Project > Clean > only myProject) I have the modal:

> Problem Occurred. Validating 'my project' has encountered a problem.
>   An internal error occurred during: validating myProject

If I click in details button, it shows the message:

> An internal error occurred during: ... java.lang.StackOverflowError.

I edited the file *eclipse.ini*, more precisely the -Xms and -Xmx properties, from 512m to 1024m, and from 1024m to 3072m.

Here is my *eclipse.ini* content file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms1024m
-Xmx3072m
```

What else I need to do to avoid the stackOverflowError? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the exact steps you tried to do. Sorry, its not clear despite your detailed description. Did you try to open a workspace in Mars that was created in Juno ? How is the OS related ? Do you see the problem on both Windows & Mac ?

Comment: I installed Eclipse Juno and Mars with separated workspaces and I made the test on both operative systems independently, Windows 7 and MacOS Sierra. The result was the same.

Comment: I have MacOS Sierra & Mars 4.5.2 with MFP 7.1 plugin and I do not see the behaviour you see. When you say "I'm trying to clean an Eclipse project " - what type of Eclipse project is this ? Is this not a MobileFirst project ?

Comment: Yes it is @Srik. Is a MobileFirst project. What configuration do you have in your eclipse.ini file?

Comment: Or if you have the download links... I downloaded MFP from [link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/)

Comment: You should perhaps open a PMR with IBM for a resolution to this issue